# Accessing a variable (from a php form) in html

Tags: php, html, forms

So I am trying to create a simple calculator. I have a form involving a couple of "drop down option/select" boxes and a submit button. For the sake of testing, you select an option and hit the submit button. I have my separate php form (testform.php) essentially echo out the selected options. However, when you hit submit, this takes you to the testform.php page and that is where it displays the selected options. My goal is for a user to select some options, hit submit and then something is displayed on the SAME page. For example, two options A and B are selected (A is "4" and B is "8") and in the form, I have a new variable that is equal to A + B. I want that new variable (result of A + B) to be displayed on the original page.

Here is some code.

inside my index.php file (ie my form)

```
<form action = 'testform.php' method = 'post' class = 'formcontainer'>

    <select name="A">
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select name="B">
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" />
</form>
```

This is my separate php form

```
<?php
    $A = $_POST["A"];
    $B = $_POST["B"];

    $result = $A + $B;
?>
```

So basically what I want to do is display the variable $result on my index page. I guess currently, my index file has no php in it, just the form. Would this sort of thing be easier to just put my php form inside the main index file? Again, this is just to keep things simple...my actual php is a bit more complex than a simple addition problem. Thanks!

Comment: put it all on the same page and use isset() against your POST arrays, or use Ajax which is beyond the scope of this question. btw, you never closed your selects

Comment: If you want both to display on the *same* page, perhaps you should put the HTML and PHP in the *same* file?

Comment: That's exactly what AJAX does

Comment: You should not use PHP if you want the result to appear right in the same page. You shoud only use Javascript to achieve that. PHP is only server-side and does require the page to be refreshed when you press Submit.

Comment: I figured you could do that with PHP but ok :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show the results on the same page, you can put it all in one file and omit the `testform.php` from `action`, and use `isset()` against your POST arrays, should you decide to add options that ask the user to select a number. I.e.: `<option value="">Please make a selection</option>`.

- `action = ''` is the same as "self", as in "same file".

Sidenote: You never closed your selects and your present code would fail in its present.

```
<form action = '' method = 'post' class = 'formcontainer'>

    <select name="A">
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select name="B">
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" />

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(isset($_POST["A"]) && isset($_POST["B"])){
    $A = $_POST["A"];
    $B = $_POST["B"];
    echo $result = $A + $B;
    }

}
?>
```

You can also use Ajax (as I mentioned in comments), but that would be beyond the scope of this question.

Sidenote: You may have noticed the echo in `echo $result = $A + $B;`. That is actually valid syntax.

Or, you can do the following, but that is just more code for nothing really.

```
$A = $_POST["A"];
$B = $_POST["B"];
$result = $A + $B;
echo $result;
```

---

**Footnotes:**

In not using `isset()` against your POST arrays, and using the entire code (HTML form and PHP) inside the same file, would trigger undefined index notices.

Comment: @ewrjontan You're most welcome, glad to have been of help. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

I have a way of doing so, I don't know if it is the best, but here it is.

index.html file: (I modified a bit)

```
<form action = 'testform.php' method = 'post' class = 'formcontainer'>

    <select name="A">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
     </select>
    <select name="B">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
     </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" />
</form>
```

testform.php file: (also modified a bit)

```
<?php
    $A = $_POST["A"];
    $B = $_POST["B"];

    $result = $A + $B;
    include 'index.php';
    print "<p>" . $result . "</p>";
?>
```

Comment: You can also check to see if the post is empty, or not all the arguments you need (both numbers) and print that you need to select the one you didn't.

Comment: *"You can also check to see if the post is empty"* - Using `<select>` will never be considered as "empty".  That is mostly checked against inputs.

Comment: I see, that is kind of stupid of me. When I just made my version of it, it started blank and then you had to select a number, It looked weird starting on a number, (OCD kicking in). But thanks anyway, I guess.

Comment: Sweet, so this works. But, based on what everyone else is saying...probably not the best way to do this? I should probably use isset() and keep everything in one file right?